# ObjC linker flag in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, linker-flags

I am working on iOS app in Swift in which I want to integrate **Google SignIn**. I have successfully integrated Google SDK in my project and I have also integrated BillDesk payment integration in my project (which is static library from billdesk `libBilldesk.a` ).

But when I run the project it gives me the error for billdesk library (`libBilldesk.a`) as `duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$` and when I removed -ObjC linker flag then it builds successfully but that time it gives error for Google SignIn as `[__NSDictionaryI gtm_httpArgumentsString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f84eb6a2d80`

I have search a lot about `-ObjC`, `-force_load`, `-all_load` but not getting any solution so please come up with your valuable solutions.

Thanks

Here are the screenshots for this...

[image: for Billdesk]

[image: for Google]

Comment: take a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html

Comment: It looks to me that you are compiling the files containing the duplicate symbols as well as them being in `libBulldesk.a`.  Do you have a source file called `UIScollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions.m` in your source tree?  BTW it's much easier for me to copy and paste large amounts of text rather than typing it out, so please include the textural versions of output rather then screenshots.

Comment: Check your static variable names in `UIScollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions` and try to rename them. This might be the source of conflict with the lib if you are using same variable name as them

Comment: also you could import some .h file twice or more in global scope

Comment: @Niko `_OBJC_CLASS_$` are Objective-C classes.  Those are the duplicates, not static variables.

Comment: @trojanfoe yeah but when I read `duplicate symbol _objc_ivar_$_` my guesses go to duplicate class or var name, could be a wrong import too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added Third party library of TPKeyboardAvoiding in your project then remove it from project (or remove reference), then after ry to run your project.

The error is mentioning duplicate symbol in

**UIScrollView+TPKeyboardAvoidingAdditions.h**

Try to check these files in your project, whether it has been added multiple times or not.